# How to use MATCH AGAINST in Mysql instead of LIKE

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-like

as everyone knows LIKE is too slow, but when I try to use MATCH AGAINST instead, its useless.

I need some operand that give the result such as LIKE '%part%' When "part" is part of the word not a complete word.

I have already tried

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE MATCH (title) AGAINST ('*part*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE MATCH (title) AGAINST ('+*part*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

and its not working

any solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can only match words with a wildcard from the beginning of the word.  As the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-boolean.html) explains:

> *
>
> The asterisk serves as the truncation (or wildcard) operator. Unlike
>   the other operators, it is appended to the word to be affected. Words
>   match if they begin with the word preceding the * operator.

Comment: so there is no other way to do something like "LIKE %%" ?